# Removing element from list with predicate

Tags: c#, list, collections, linked-list

I have a list from the .NET collections library and I want to remove a single element. Sadly, I cannot find it by comparing directly with another object.

I fear that using `FindIndex` and `RemoveAt` will cause multiple traversals of the list.

I don't know how to use Enumerators to remove elements, otherwise that could have worked.

`RemoveAll` does what I need, but will not stop after one element is found.

Ideas?

Comment: Could you show some example code?

Comment: The questions is tagged `linked-list` but the description suggests `List<T>`. Which is it?

Comment: I thought List was a kind of linked list? Is it not?

Comment: @Steinbitglis: `List<T> ` is not a linked-list; it's a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

Comment: @Steinbitglis: No, it's not. It's array-backed.

Comment: To clarify - you want to remove the _first_ match, even if there are multiple?

Comment: Do you really need to use a List? It seems to me that an HashSet or a Dictionary would be better suited in this case (with O(1) constant-time add, remove and find operations).

Comment: I think actually that the constant factors of HashSet and Dictionary would blow this out of proportions. But I'm looking into LinkedList, since that's what I thought I had in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Now the OP has changed to use a `LinkedList<T>`, it's easy to give an answer which only iterates as far as it has to:

```
public static void RemoveFirst<T>(LinkedList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    var node = list.First;
    while (node != null)
    {
        if (predicate(node.Value))
        {
            list.Remove(node);
            return;
        }
        node = node.Next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking only to remove a single element.

Comment: @Steinbitglis: Will there be multiple values which match the predicate? And what sort of list are you using?

Comment: @Steinbitglis: Edited to show how you can use a side-effect to use `RemoveAll`.

Comment: This is the solution I was ultimately looking for, so I'm marking this as the accepted answer, whether it's deserved or not.

Comment: If it is the answer, which helped you most, then it is definitively deserved. This is the meaning of "accepted".

Answer (score 17):

`List<T>` has a `FindIndex` method that accepts a predicate

```
int index = words.FindIndex(s => s.StartsWith("x"));
if (index >= 0)
{
    words.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Removes first word starting with "x". `words` is assumed to be a `List<string>` in this example.

Comment: If list has a constant-time index lookup, I think this will be ok. I was worried that RemoveAt would also traverse the list.

Comment: @Steinbitglis: It's an O(n) operation, because it has to copy everything. Did you actually *want* a linked list?

Comment: Well, I have very few elements, that keep coming and going. I think at least hashtable would be stupid. I don't see any problems with linked lists, other than this seemingly trivial optimization that I can't figure out.

Comment: I switched to LinkedList and I hope I will get Deque-like operations, where I mostly check 1 or 2 elements.

Comment: @Steinbitglis: If you want LinkedList, I'll undelete my answer, as it already contains a solution for you...

Comment: In order to find an item based on a predicate, both list types require a list traversal, which is an O(n) operation. Removing an item from a `List<T>` at a specific index is O(n) because items have to be moved. Removing an item from a `LinkedList<T>` at the current node is an O(1) operation. *(Replaces an old comment that I removed).*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove only **the first** element that matches a predicate you can use the following (example):

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Remove(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x = 10));
```

where `(x => x = 10)` is obviously your predicate for matching the objects.

Comment: This requires the list to be enumerated twice. Once to find a matching item. Once to find this item again in `Remove`.

Comment: True, using RemoveAt is more efficient.

Comment: I guess it fails if FirstOrDefault returns null

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need same thing, but for `IList<T>`
(Inspired by Strillo answer, but more efficient)

```
public bool Remove(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if(predicate(list[i]))
        {
            list.RemoveAt(i);
            return true;
        }                   
    }   

    return false;
}
```